# Commerce 2 Adding tax to custom adjuster

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

I have created a custom adjuster, there is a surcharge per item if a customer has selected rush delivery. But i need to charge tax on that adjuster. Below is code:

```
public function adjust(Order $order): array
{
    $adjustments = [];

    foreach ($order->getLineItems() as $item) {
        $adjustment = new OrderAdjustment;
        $adjustment->type = 'rush-delivery';
        $adjustment->name = 'Rush Delivery';
        $adjustment->description = 'Rush Delivery';
        $adjustment->sourceSnapshot = ['data' => 'value']; // This can contain information about how the adjustment came to be
        $adjustment->amount = 1;
        $adjustment->setOrder($order);
        $adjustment->setLineItem($item);

        $adjustments[] = $adjustment;
    }

    return $adjustments;
}
```

But tax is not added to the £1 i am adding here. How can i get tax to be added or calculated as included?

Answer (score 3):

Having slept on it i thought it could be something to do with the order of the adjusters. Maybe Tax was applying to the price before my custom adjuster. So in the event i did the following:

```
var_dump($event->types)
```

This told me that my custom adjuster was going to the bottom of this array. To resolve this i used the php function array_unshift to push it to the front of the array

```
array_unshift($event->types,MyAdjuster::class);
```

This now gave me the following array:

```
array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(18) "modules\MyAdjuster"
      [1]=>
      string(33) "craft\commerce\adjusters\Shipping"
      [2]=>
      string(33) "craft\commerce\adjusters\Discount"
      [3]=>
      string(28) "craft\commerce\adjusters\Tax"
    }
```

As you can see the adjuster is at the front of the array and now the tax applies to the fee as required.

Comment: When you say "in the event" do you mean EVENT_REGISTER_ORDER_ADJUSTERS?